# Difference between req.sessionID and req.session.id in express-session

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

Can someone explain me the difference between [req.sessionID](https://github.com/expressjs/session#reqsessionid-1) and [req.session.id](https://github.com/expressjs/session#reqsessionid) with an example? In a request shouldn't they be same always?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is none. Use [the source](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/session/session.js#L26).

Excerpt of the relevant constructor function:

```
function Session(req, data) {
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'req', { value: req });
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'id', { value: req.sessionID });

  // ...
}
```

The reason why there are two ways to get the session ID is either "for convenience" or "for backward compatibility" – very probably both.